# How to mute FLVPlayback on default?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm using the default flv player component in Flash cs4. I want my video to start on page load, but I would like it to be muted in the beginning, so the visitors can chose to unmute it if they want.

I tried to google and found a number of solutions which doesn't work for me(or rather I don't know how to make it work).

There seems to be a good solution here: http://bangersandflash.net/muting-flvplayback-component-by-default/

But the zip link is broken, and I'm not sure how to piece the tutorial together.

Is someone able to help me shed some light into this situation by providing me an example fla file?

**Edit:** I tried something like this but unfortunately it didn't seem to work:

```
myVideo.volume = 0;

myVideo.muteButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent) {
    myVideo.volume = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var flag:Boolean;
foo.volume = 0;
foo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, action);
function action (e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    if(!flag){
            foo.volume = 1;
            flag = true;
        }else{
            foo.volume =0;
            flag = false;
        }       
}
```

Comment: Yes but that turns the volume off all together and the mute button that comes with the flayer skin loses its function. I need the sound to turn back on when user toggles the mute button.

Comment: then, when user toggles the button set to 1.

Comment: Hi Benny, thank you for your reply. I've updated my initial question with what I tried, but unfortunately it didn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi Benny, thank you again. I replaced foo with my FLVPlayback instance name "myVideo", but unfortunately it still doesn't work....in fact nothing happens. If I put `myVideo.volume=0;` in the first line, it just completely mutes the sound and the mutebutton doesn't work. Did it work when you tested it? Would it be possible for me to download your file?

Comment: nope. last time I did a stupid updation. Sry for that. chk now.

Comment: I would give you a big kiss right now..You're an absolute savior!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep the functionality of the player skin, use this:

```
mc_video.volume=0;
mc_video._uiMgr._isMuted = true;
```

am aware this is an old question, but someone might still need this answer.